# How to use custom initializer on an Realm object inside a class with generic type?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, realm

I have a class called `ObjectManager` which has generic type `O: Object, Persistable`. This way I can have one class that can operate with multiple different subclasses of realm `Object`. But the problem is in the last line  `cache = O(message: "hello world")` the error is:  **Incorrect argument label in call (have 'message:', expected 'value:')**

When typing it suggests me that I can use initializer of `Persistable` protocol, but complain during the compiling, that it expect an initializer from `Object` class. Is it possible to cast Persistable initializer?

```
protocol Persistable {
  init(message: String)
}

class CustomObject: Object, Persistable {
  dynamic var message: String = ""
  required convenience init(message: String) {
    self.init()
    self.message = message
  }
}

class ObjectManager<O>: NSObject where O: Object, O: Persistable {
  var cache: O?

  func didReceive(message: String) {
    cache = O(message: "hello world")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your `CustomObject` class final, and replace your initializer with a factory method, you will get code which does what you want. Unfortunately, the Swift compiler error messages are so cryptic in this case as to be completely unhelpful.

```
protocol Persistable {
    static func factory(message: String) -> Self
}

final class CustomObject: Object, Persistable {
    dynamic var message: String = ""
    static func factory(message: String) -> CustomObject {
        let x = CustomObject()
        x.message = message
        return x
    }
}

class ObjectManager<O>: NSObject where O: Object, O: Persistable {
    var cache: O?

    func didReceive(message: String) {
        cache = O.factory(message: "hello world")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm i dont know if I make it right, but putting it that way, doesnt work
`final class CustomObject: Object, Persistable {
}`

Comment: Ah, I had changed the `O : Object` constraint to `O : CustomObject` and not changed it back. In that case, what you want is to replace the initializer with a static factory method (e.g. `protocol Persistable { static func factory(message: String) -> Self }`). That does work correctly, even when the version with the initializers fails.

Comment: Ok, this works, thanks. Maybe you can update the answer.